# How to sort table column data alphanumerically in table sorter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I want to sort a table using table sorter in Javascript. But when there are alphanumeric data in the column, then it is not sorting properly.

For instance:

```
order1023
order1145
quote786
invoice1253
quote1010
```

I tried by giving headers: `{ 0: {sorter: 'text'}}, textExtraction: "complex"}`
But I am getting result as:

```
quote1010
order1023
order1145
invoice1253
quote786
```

I want result as

```
invoice1253
order1023
order1145
quote786
quote1010
```

Comment: "using table sorter" - Which one?

Answer (score 1):

you should add a [parser](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html) as bellow,

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: 'alphanum',
  is: function(s) {
    return false;
  },
  format: function(s) {
    var str = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})/g, function(a){
        return pad(a);
    });

    return str;
  },
  type: 'text'
});

function pad(num ){
  var s = '00000' + num;
  return s.substr(s.length-5);
}
```

when initializing,

```
$(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        headers: { 
            6: { // column number
                sorter:'alphanum' 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: everything working fine.. but we have to use "/d+" in the place of "/d{1,2}".. why becoz we dont know the size of the number..

Comment: if you find the answer here, just mark it as correct, that will help other users.